Google Sheets script to delete week-old rows across all tabs
I am a new to this stuff and have been working to solve a problem I was hoping someone could help me with.
I am looking to automatically delete rows in Column A of all sheets except one ['Top Level Data'] based on whether the date in Column A is older than 1 week.
function weekOldDelete () {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var datarange = s.getDataRange();
    var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
    var values = datarange.getValues();
    var weekOld = new Date()
    weekOld = new Date(weekOld.getTime()-7*3600000*24)
    var excludes = ['Top Level Data'];
    if (excludes.indexOf(s.getName()) != -1) return;
    for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
        var tempDate = values[i-1][0];// 
        if (tempDate <= weekOld)
        {
          sheet.deleteRow(i);
        } 
        else {}
    }
}


I see that you are a fairly new user here at StackOverflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

What's wrong with the current script? Is there an error? See "Describe the problem" in [mcve]

Delete Week Old Rows Using new Date()
I tested your code and modified it and made the script work.
I use map() and foreach() method to get the data on the sheets. Add seven on the New Date and compare if the Date is more than Seven Days Today.
Whole Script:
function weekOlddelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var excludes = ['Top Level Data'];
  var sh = ss.getSheets().filter(x => !excludes.includes(x.getSheetName()) && !x.isSheetHidden()).map(x => x.getSheetName());

  sh.forEach(x => {
    var range = ss.getSheetByName(x);
    var data = range.getRange(1, 1, range.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
    data.shift();
    for (var i = data.length; i > 0; i--) {
      if (data[i - 1] !== '') {
        var date = new Date(data[i - 1])
        var plusSeven = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
        if (plusSeven < new Date()) range.deleteRow(i + 1);
      }
    }
    console.log('End of ', x)
  })
}

Reference:

map()

ForEach



If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer.
